# How to pass self into a decorated method?

Tags: python, private, python-decorators, public

I'm trying to implement privacy modifiers into python using decorators.
My problem is that whenever I decorate a method that has self as an argument, when the method is called using dot notation, it doesn't pass self in automatically.

Public decorator class:

```py
class Public:
    def __init__(self, method, *args):
        if type(method).__name__ == 'function':
            self.method = method

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.method(*args, **kwargs)
```

Example code:

```py
class Test:
    @Public
    def test(self):
        return "Hello"


class Test1(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.test())


x = Test1()
```

How do I pass self into `Public.__call__`?

I tried regularly passing in self:

```py
class Test:
    @Public
    def test(self):
        return "Hello"


class Test1(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.test(self))


x = Test1()
```

which works but I would much rather not have to do that every time I need to call a method.

Comment: Why are your trying to add privacy modifiers to python? Are you aware that the entirety of an object is stored in a publicly visible dictionary, and so private members are impossible?

Comment: Are you aware that there are decorators that make it possible? I’m just doing this for fun to learn how to use decorators.

Comment: `self` **is** passed into `__call__`. It's just that, since this is the `__call__` method of the `Public` class, `self` is the `Public` instance, not the `Test` instance.

Comment: @TysonChicken give me an example that you think makes this possible

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer

Here's how if anyone else is doing something similar:

First I had to create a decorator function that changed the **getattribute** function in the class

```
def modifiable(cls):
    if isinstance(cls, type):
        original_getattr = cls.__getattribute__

        def getattr(_self, name):
            attr = original_getattr(_self, name)

            if isinstance(attr, Modifier):

                def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    return attr(_self, *args, **kwargs)

                return wrapper

            return attr

        cls.__getattribute__ = getattr

    return cls
```

I also created an empty `Modifier` class that all the privacy modifiers inherit from to make it easier to check if a method is modified.

example code:

```
@modifiable
class Test:
    @Protected
    def test(self):
        return "Hello"


@modifiable
class Test1(Test):
    x = 1

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.test())

test = Test1()
print(test.test())
```

and output:

```
Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tyson\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\better-decorators\src\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(test.test())
privacy.AccessError: test is a protected method
```

(privacy.AccessError is a custom error)

Comment: You might be interested in checking out [Descriptors: HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), in particular, pay attention to [these examples](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) and then think how that could be applied to your `Modifier` objects to not require `modifiable`